# dialup connection script

Tags: networking, script, modem, isp, dial-up

I've just started working for a company who produce a specialist modem.  In the test department they simulate actual use with a bunch of pc's acting as clients connecting over this modem.  As such each needs to dial a set of dial-up connections.  Each of these has to be created manually, and currently takes quite a while on each machine, so i was hoping to be able to automate the creation process.

Back in the early days of the internet i remember getting CD's from ISP's where the dial-up connection was configured automatically, and i was wondering if anyone lknew how to do this, or if they could point me in the direction of a tutorial about it.

To be clear, i don't want to automate actually dialing the connection, but i do want to run a script which creates the icons in the networking applet that allows us to dial these connection.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can automate dial up connections using `CMAK` and `IEAK`. As far as dialing goes, you can create shortcuts to them and then call the shortcuts from the batch file. The latter will not be easy, the shortcuts are different on each computer.

You may want to look into a more robust solution like the Win32 Remote Access Library, although you will need to be capable of programming a solution in C/C++.

Comment: OK, CMAK looks like it's *possible* to use, but am i imagining the old .inf files or similar that used to be disrtibuted by ISP's in the good'ole dial-up days?